# Динамическое изменение swiper slider ( react )

Tags: javascript, reactjs, swiper

Есть слайдер swiper у которого прописан параметр mousewheel = true ( переключение слайдов за счёт колесика мышки ). Нужно чтобы при нажатие на кнопку он менял этот параметр на false и данная функция ( прокуратка колесиком мышки ) была откл. Я создал useState, который изменяется при нажатие на кнопку, но функция прокрутки колесиком мышки остается, как это можно исправить ?

```
<Swiper
    pagination={pagination}
    className='homeSliders'
    allowTouchMove={true}
    speed={1000}
    mousewheel={scrollSlider}
    modules={[Mousewheel, Pagination]}
    onSlideChange={closeDetails}
    shouldSwiperUpdate
>
```

```
const [scrollSlider, setScrollSlider] = useState(true)

const DetailsOne = () => {
    setScrollSlider(!scrollSlider)
}
```